# Como retornar al usuario a la pagina principal si no esta logueado o cerro la sesión

Tags: php, html, mysql, login

Necesito saber como lograr que el usuario sea devuelto a login.php si no tiene la sesión iniciada. Este es mi codigo:

login.php

```
<?php
// Include config file
require ('connection.php');

if (isset($_POST['usuario']) and isset($_POST['contrasena'])){
//3.1.1 Assigning posted values to variables.
$usuario = $_POST['usuario'];
$contrasena = $_POST['contrasena'];
//3.1.2 Checking the values are existing in the database or not
$query = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE usuario='$usuario' and contrasena='$contrasena'";

$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query) or die(mysqli_error($connection));
$count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
//3.1.2 If the posted values are equal to the database values, then session will be created for the user.
if ($count == 1){
$_SESSION['usuario'] = $usuario;
}else{
//3.1.3 If the login credentials doesn't match, he will be shown with an error message.
$fmsg = "Invalid Login Credentials.";
}
}
//3.1.4 if the user is logged in Greets the user with message
if (isset($_SESSION['usuario'])){
$usuario = $_SESSION['usuario'];
header('Location: menu-ppal.php');

}else{
//3.2 When the user visits the page first time, simple login form will be displayed.

?>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Iniciar Sesion</title>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" >

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" >

<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" >

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
      <form class="form-signin" method="POST">
      <?php if(isset($fmsg)){ ?><div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert"> <?php echo $fmsg; ?> </div><?php } ?>
        <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Please Login</h2>
        <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">Nombre de Usuario</span>
      <input type="text" name="usuario" class="form-control" placeholder="Nombre de usuario" required>
    </div>
        <label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only">Contraseña</label>
        <input type="password" name="contrasena" id="contrasena" class="form-control" placeholder="Contraseña" required>
        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Acceder</button>
      </form>
</div>

</body>

</html>
<?php } ?>
```

menu-ppal.php

```
<?php
require ('connection.php');



?>
<html dir="ltr" lang="es">
  <head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="content-type">
    <title>Menú Principal</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <a href="logout.php">Cerrar Sesion</a><br>
    <div>
      <table style="width: 70%;" border="0">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td style="text-align: center; width: 33%; background-color: white;"><img

                style="width: 166px; height: 166px;" alt="icono-buques" src="img/Icono%20Buques.png"></td>
            <td style="text-align: center; width: 33%; margin-left: 36px; background-color: white;"><img

                style="width: 166px; height: 166px;" alt="icono-nominaciones" src="img/Icono%20Nominaciones.png"><br>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 33%; text-align: center; background-color: white; height: 170.95px;"><img

                style="width: 166px; height: 166px;" alt="icono-documentos" src="img/Icono%20Documentos.png"><br>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td style="width: 33%; text-align: center; background-color: white;"><br>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 33%; text-align: center; background-color: white;"><br>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 33%; text-align: center; background-color: white;"><br>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes ocupar el valor de `$_SESSION['usuario']`, si no existe, retornarlo al login. Hacer algún servicio, clase o algo así que valide que exista ese valor.

```
if (isset($_SESSION['usuario'])) {
    //si existe
} else {
    //no existe, debes redireccionar
}
```

Comment: Eso siempre funciona, además si quieres un código más limpio puedes crear un archivo php encargado de verificar la sesión y luego incluirlo con require_once en otros archivos para centralizar las modificaciones a futuro y no tener que estar archivo por archivo cambiando una ruta.
Recuerda que también puedes modificar el tiempo de las sesiones en php.ini

Comment: estoy colocando para la redireccion `header("Location: login.php")` pero asi loguee, me devuelve a login.php, creo que ahora el problema estaría en login.php, a lo mejor no se esta iniciando la SESSION, pero no se donde está el problema

Comment: @eduardoimm revisa la variable SESSION

Comment: bueno, en login.php veo que se esta definiendo en el siguiente fragmento
`if ($count == 1){
$_SESSION['usuario'] = $usuario;`
ya que si no no ejecutara este otro fragmento
`if (isset($_SESSION['usuario'])){
$usuario = $_SESSION['usuario'];
header('Location: menu-ppal.php');`
si me está enviando a menu-ppal.php, y alla al ejecutar correr el código `if (isset($_SESSION['usuario']))`, ejecuta el else, lo probe con unos simples `echo`, no entiendo donde está el error

Comment: Te falta session_star(); al inicio!!!!

Comment: @sioesi en que parte especificamente?

Comment: En todos los archivos donde ocupes o setees valores de SESSION debes iniciarlo

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72746/discussion-between-eduardoimm-and-sioesi).

Comment: @sioesi listo, muchas gracias